# Can percona-cluster be used with LXC

Tags: juju

Can percona-cluster charm be safely placed in anto LXC containers? If so, what would be the juju commands to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a percona expert, but looking over the charm I don't see anything obvious that would restrict it to only a "real" machine, or VM.  Before starting, please be familar with the charm README as you will need to follow it closely, and as it is changing very frequently, I don't feel it would be best to type it all out here:

- http://manage.jujucharms.com/~openstack-charmers/precise/percona-cluster

You can target each unit to an LXC in turn with the `--to` parameter, as follows:

```
# Instead of deploying to a machine, use --to lxc:0
juju deploy --config percona.yaml percona-cluster --to lxc:0

# wait till new unit is 'started', then:
juju add-unit percona-cluster --to lxc:0

# wait till new unit is 'started', then:
juju add-unit percona-cluster --to lxc:0
```

Keep in mind that as of this writing, LXCs are not externally network addressable outside their host machine except on the MAAS provider, so you will need to have them all on the same piece of hardware (and whatever is using them on the same hardware as well).  What that implies is that this type of deploy would only make sense for testing purposes.

Once juju supports network addressable LXCs on other providers, you could spread out the LXCs to other machines in the environment using these same primitives combined with `juju add-machine` first.